# How to slide to the right my divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating a list of divs that I want to slide. Each slide has its own image and some kind of description. I've seen several methods for sliding, but I still can't build one by myself.

The idea I'm looking for:

- Create a list of divs. The first one visible
- When I press 'Next' or 'Previous' see the next or previous element of the list and hide/fade/slide right the other one

The slide transitions need to be right, in case.

I'm not asking you to build the code for me, but any suggestions would be apreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are many javascript carousel plugins out there, especially as plugins for frameworks like jQuery.

[jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) is one of the most popular but a simple google search will show a lot of results. most of them will allow you to configure the scrolling direction and how many elements you want to display, and much more.

Comment: Yes, I've looked for some of them. But some of them are quite complicated, and my level drives me to build a simpler one. This link is REALLY interesting for a newbie like me! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont insist to build one from scratch you can use

[BxSlider](http://bxslider.com/)

It lets you configure many settings along with transition, speed, pager links and have lots of callback method which you might need at some point.

There are pleanty of other options available.

Comment: I need to say... yes! really interesting one!

Answer (score 1):

Well first, there are a lot of plugins out there, where you could read the code to understand their markup.

Basic idea is the following:

You have a left floating list (`<ul>`) where your item (in this case image) would obviously be the `<li>`-Tag. This tags have a constant `width`. Wrap a div around the list with the constant items `width` and set `overflow-x:hidden;` to the div.

In you javascript you calculate `var maxWidth = constantWidth * numberOfElements`.

When a prev/next click happens, you just +/- the constant with to the `margin-left` style attribute of the `<ul>`-Tag. When you do this with jQuerys `.animate()` method you have a decent sliding effect. To capture a sliding outside the element you use the `maxWidth` variable and check it against the calculated `margin-left` before executing the animation.

Comment: Interesting... this is the manual way I was looking for. But I need to say that I'm looking all of your answers. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Look at some of these;

http://www.blogohblog.com/20-killer-image-sliders-carousels/